# git python pre-commit hook to add files

Tags: git, python-2.7, pre-commit-hook

I have a `pre-commit-hook` written in python, which does some changes for a file. Now I would want to also add this file, to include the changes the `pre-commit-hook` does.

I tried to use `subprocess` to do this

```
subprocess.check_call(('git', 'add', filename))
```

If I try this in the interactive python session it properly adds the file, but I the hook it doesn't work.
I already checked out, that the hook works form the proper directory.

How can I add files the right way?

**Edit:**
My `git` version is 2.1.4

Comment: First, make sure your hook is really running (have it print or log something, for instance). If it's not being run, nothing you do to it will have any effect! If it really *is* being run, the next step depends on your Git version. (In any case, a hook that *modifies what is to be committed* is generally not a good idea: these hooks should merely *verify*, and exit 0 or nonzero to allow or prevent the commit.)

Comment: I checked that my hook is running (using some print statements). The reason I want to add the a file, is because the hook adds a version number after verifying the files. A hook is the only safe way I know to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting: as long as the pre-commit hook really is running, the `git add` should take effect in any Git version later than 1.5.4.  See [this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2888605c649ccd423232161186d72c0e6c458a48) in the Git repository for Git.

(I remember having this not work correctly in some version of Git, but do not recall it being broken in any specific version.)

The alternative, if this is broken in your particular Git version, is to have your pre-commit hook add the file, run *its own* `git commit` that arranges to have the inner, recursive commit *not* recurse again—it's up to you how to work this out—and then when the inner commit finishes, reject the commit.  This solution is ugly since it makes every commit seem to fail.